# Re-inputing string date in gui not possible after validation and triggering an error

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, pysimplegui

I have the following code that asks for date input and checks if the date is valid.

- When I run the code, specified layout is displayed in window; all good.
- Inputting 13 for month in input field (not via calendar button) and clicking OK brings me to the `str2date` function. This triggers a `ValueError` and `False` is returned.
- I expected that `continue` would give me the possibility to correct the mistake in the input field, but this field is not editable. Only when I click calendar button,I can input again.

Is there a way which would make editing possible after a wrong input?

````
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date, datetime

# Input and Calendar are have matching key/target (-Start-)

layout = [[sg.T('Choosing start date')], 
         [sg.T(text='Start:', s=(6,1)),sg.I(key='-Start-', size=(9,1),change_submits=False), 
             sg.CalendarButton("Calendar", close_when_date_chosen=True, target='-Start-', 
             no_titlebar=False, default_date_m_d_y=(1,1,None),format='%Y-%m-%d')],
         [sg.Ok(), sg.Exit()]]

def str2date(a):
    '''If date string is valid, return date object. Else, return False'''
    try:
        return dt.datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    except ValueError:
        sg.popup_no_titlebar('Not a valid date','try again', button_color='Red', font=font)
        return False

font = 'Helvetica 14'
window = sg.Window('Getting date input', layout, font=font)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    print(event, values)
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        sg.popup(f'Existing ...{chr(10)}Untill next time', no_titlebar=True, font=font)
    elif event == 'Ok':
        if str2date(values['-Start-']):
            sg.popup_no_titlebar(values['-Start-'], font=font)
        else:
            continue
    break

window.close()```
````

Comment: Not my downvote, but we'd really need to see some debugging effort. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: The GUI parts are not really useful for asking about the underlying logic, and prevent many of us from spending the time to set up whatever it takes to attempt to reproduce your problem. Adding a few print statements would probably reveal to you where the logic is not doing what you hope.

Answer (score 0):

My code was OK, but I believe there is a problem with `no_titlebar` on a Mac in Tkinter.
If I change the code like this:

```
def str2date(a):
    """If date string is valid, return date object. Else, return False"""
    try:
        return dt.datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    except ValueError:
        sg.popup('Not a valid date', 'try again', button_color='Red', font=font)
        return False
```

My problem is solved!